# How to implement Typeorm With MongoGridFS in nestjs?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to create the instance of MongoGridFS like below

```
import { Db } from 'mongodb';

@Injectable()
export class WebsiteService {
     constructor(@InjectDataSource() private source: DataSource) {
         const mongoClient = (this.source.driver as any).queryRunner.databaseConnection as MongoClient;
         
         const db: Db = mongoClient.db(); (In this line throwing error like mongodb.d.ts(2997, 5): 'runCursorCommand' is declared here. )
         const fileModel = new MongoGridFS(this.db);
     }
}
```

This code is throwing error like (In this line throwing error like mongodb.d.ts(2997, 5): 'runCursorCommand' is declared here.)

const db: Db = mongoClient.db();

Due to that error unable to proceed to do actions like readFileStream is not working.

Please help me